# Simple PHP + MySQL Form Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, so recently I watched a tutorial and coded along with it in Notepad++.  I am attempting a simple MYSQL login/register form, but when I login- it gives me the "Wrong U/P" error echo I wrote.  It saves everything in the database as the md5 and stuff.  Here is my codes.

register.php

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Preform the verification of the nation
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

if($email1 == $email2) {
if($pass1 == $pass2) {
//All good.  Carry on.


$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$email1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email1']);
$email2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email2']);
$pass1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$pass2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);

$pass1 = md5($pass1);


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
echo "Sorry, that user already exists!";
exit();
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name',  '$lname',  '$uname',  '$email1',  '$pass1')");




}else{
echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match<br><br>";
exit();

}
}else{
echo "Sorry, your emails do not match.<br><br>";

}






}else{

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;

}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$pass = md5($pass);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECET * FROM `users` where `uname` = '$uname' and `pass` = '$pass'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "You are now logged in.";


exit();
}else{
echo "Wrong U/P combination";
}


}else{
$form = <<<EOT
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input tye="text" name="uname" /><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
EOT;

echo "$form";
}

?>
```

and config.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "X", "X");
mysql_select_db("X");

?>
```

The config.php code is correct, but I am not giving away X.

As you can see, this code echos out an error for login.php if it's incorrect.  It gives me that error even if it is correct.  I used MD5 hash passes, so please help!

Comment: Typo `SELECET` instead of `SELECT`.

Comment: compulsory, stop using mysql_* functions comment.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're using the ` tag in there - this should be ' .

You need to either interpolate or concatenate your variables; i.e; instead of

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name',  '$lname',  '$uname',  '$email1',  '$pass1')");
```

use;

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('id', 'name', 'lname', 'uname', 'email', 'pass') VALUES (NULL, '{$name}',  '{$lname}',  '{$uname}',  '{$email1}',  '{$pass1}')");
```

Anyway, aside from some good practice, have a look at this line;

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECET * FROM `users` where `uname` = '$uname' and `pass` = '$pass'");
```

Just a small typo ruining everything for you. Change SELECET to SELECT , and you should be good to go.

Best of luck!

- Eoghan

Comment: Actually, the ` character is perfectly fine when referencing column/field names.

Comment: @TiesonT. I see, thanks for the heads up. For the purposes of someone just learning php and SQL, I think it'd still be easier for him to just stick with ' , but noted! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need the following lines:

   `$email2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email2']);`

and

```
`$pass2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);`
```

2. run `SELECET * FROM users` in order to see that the user/pwd really made it to the DB
3. add `echo "$uname $pass <br>";` to the login form to make sure that it passed correctly

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct, but you have a more fundamental issue with this: you are using the old, deprecated mysql_* functions. Those functions are an old, procedural interface to MySQL and don't support the modern features of that RDBMS. I suggest using mysqli or PDO for an OOP approach to database access.

If you are going to stick to this ancient code, you should at least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `mysql_escape_string()`.